# how to handle tableview scroll keyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, keyboard

I have a tableview with cells with textFields, and a button at the end, outside the tableview, anchored to bottom anchor.
My code seems good for big phones, but on iPhone 8 it fails, with button being right on the top of keyboard accessory view (if present). I think is classic issue, but I cannot use other solutions for my case.

in my viewDidLoad:

```
bindKeyboardNotifications(using: bottomContraintButtonSuperView, view: myTable)

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        //dismiss keyboard observer
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

in controller's exentsion

```
 ///handles the scroll of the keyboard based on a given constraint outlet
    func bindKeyboardNotifications(using constraint: NSLayoutConstraint, view: UITableView? = nil) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height ?? 0
//            constraint.constant  = -20 + keyboardHeight
            constraint.constant = keyboardHeight
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
            constraint.constant = 20.0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This library is helpful to get rid of this problem

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding